# iteration without a loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration, memo

The following example is from "Think Python" book by Allen Downey. While explaining the concept of "Memos" in dictionaries, he quotes the following example.

```
known = {0:0, 1:1}
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    known[n] = res
    return res
fibonacci(5)
print known
```

I was expecting this code to return `{0:0, 1:1, 5:5}` since I don't see any iteration to compute the function for each value between 1 and 5. But what I see is `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5}` returned when the code is run (as the book says it would), but I can't understand why the function computed expression `res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)` for n=2, n=3 and n=4.

Can someone please explain this to me? I can't quite get the explanation in the book.

Comment: This is *recursion*, not *iteration*. Why do you think SO can explain it any better than the book can?

Comment: Code analysis is not pattern matching, in order to understand what is happening you should follow each line of code, take a piece of paper and simulate what happens - this is the best way to learn, and the answer to this question will appear quite easily

Comment: Step away from the computer and follow the algorithm yourself. You'll do exactly the same thing the computer does.

Comment: A pair of recursive calls is the naive recursive Fibonacci implementation, by the way.

Comment: jonrsharpe: I thought posting here will help me, because I can't expect book author to take time to interact with all the readers, where as with SO, I can interact with the whole community and can possibly get answer to my question, as I was able to. Thank you.

Comment: I totally, 100% get it, now. As I said I am a rookie here, and now I see what my mistake was. I didn't see recursion at first, because in my mind (I don't know how and why), I was fixated on "res = (n-1) + (n-2)" where as the function clearly states "res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)" thus calling the function from within itself. Everyone who responded saw it right away. I hope I will be able to develop cognitive recognition of items in code as I deal more and more with the code. It is crystal clear now. Thanks to every one who responded.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting print statements into the code to keep track of the state of `known`:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    print(n, known)
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

    known[n] = res
    return res
fibonacci(5)
print(known)
```

yields

```
5 {0: 0, 1: 1}
4 {0: 0, 1: 1}
3 {0: 0, 1: 1}
2 {0: 0, 1: 1}
1 {0: 0, 1: 1}
0 {0: 0, 1: 1}
1 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}
2 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2}
3 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5}
```

The first (integer) value is the value of `n`. As you can see, `fibonacci(5)` is
called, then `fibonacci(4)`, then `fibonacci(3)`, then `fibonacci(2)` and so
on. These calls are all due to Python encountering

```
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

and recursively calling `fibonacci(n-1)`. Remember, Python evaluates expressions
from left to right. So only after `fibonacci(n-1)` returns is `fibonacci(n-2)`
called.

To better understand the order of the recursive function calls you could use
this decorator:

```
import functools

def trace(f):
    """This decorator shows how the function was called.
    Especially useful with recursive functions."""
    indent = ' ' * 2

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
        arg_str = ', '.join(
            ['{0!r}'.format(a) for a in arg]
            + ['{0} = {1!r}'.format(key, val) for key, val in kw.items()])
        function_call = '{n}({a})'.format(n=f.__name__, a=arg_str)
        print("{i}--> {c}".format(
            i=indent * (trace.level), c=function_call))
        trace.level += 1
        try:
            result = f(*arg, **kw)
            print("{i}<-- {c} returns {r}".format(
                i=indent * (trace.level - 1), c=function_call, r=result))
        finally:
            trace.level -= 1
        return result
    trace.level = 0
    return wrapper

known = {0:0, 1:1}
@trace
def fibonacci(n):
    # print(n, known)
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

    known[n] = res
    return res
fibonacci(5)
print(known)
```

which yields

```
--> fibonacci(5)                         
  --> fibonacci(4)                        # fibonacci(5) calls fibonacci(4)
    --> fibonacci(3)                      # fibonacci(4) calls fibonacci(3)
      --> fibonacci(2)                    # fibonacci(3) calls fibonacci(2)
        --> fibonacci(1)                  # fibonacci(2) calls fibonacci(1)
        <-- fibonacci(1) returns 1
        --> fibonacci(0)                  # fibonacci(2) calls fibonacci(0)
        <-- fibonacci(0) returns 0
      <-- fibonacci(2) returns 1
      --> fibonacci(1)                    # fibonacci(3) calls fibonacci(1)
      <-- fibonacci(1) returns 1
    <-- fibonacci(3) returns 2
    --> fibonacci(2)                      # fibonacci(4) calls fibonacci(2) 
    <-- fibonacci(2) returns 1
  <-- fibonacci(4) returns 3
  --> fibonacci(3)                        # fibonacci(5) calls fibonacci(3) 
  <-- fibonacci(3) returns 2
<-- fibonacci(5) returns 5
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5}
```

You can tell by the level of indentation where each recursive call is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is very helpful and on point in clearing up my confusion. I am a beginner for coding and have not come across the the recursion in the context of function evaluation. I am familiar with "recursion" in the domain of my expertise (IP routing), where it is a much simpler concept. Thanks for taking time to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

As you see `fibonacci` is a recursive function, which means it calls itself inside the function.

For example consider `fibonacci(2)`. `2` is not in `known`dictionary, so `res = fibonacci(1)+fibonacci(0)` is executed. Because `0` and `1` are known , their values (0 and 1) adding into `res` so `res=1` so `fibonacci(2) = 1` and 2 is also added into the `known` dictionary and it goes until reaches 5.